# SQL LEFT JOIN & AND Keyword

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently have a function which uses the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT `plans`.`concurrents` 
FROM `plans` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`membership` = `plans`.`ID` 
WHERE `users`.`ID` = ?`
```

I am trying to add into the SQL statement so it also adds on the value within the 'extra_concurrents' column in the 'users' table to the value which is returned from the SQL statement above.

I tried but have no luck:

```
SELECT `plans`.`concurrents` 
FROM `plans` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`membership` AND `users`.`extra_concurrents` = `plans`.`ID` 
WHERE `users`.`ID` = ?`
```

I need to return the total value of plans.concurrents and users.extra_concurrents added together

Comment: Can you give an example of what the table looks like

Comment: what is required ?

Comment: @Aman I need to return the total valuie of `plans`.`concurrents` and `users`.`extra_concurrents` added together.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @Aman perfection! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I need to say something about your query.  The `left join` is utterly unnecessary.  Your `where` clause is turning it into an inner join.

Then, I recommend table aliases, to simplify the query.  And the rest is addition:

```
SELECT p.concurrents + coalesce(u.extra_concurrents, 0)
FROM plans p JOIN
     users u
     ON u.membership = p.ID
WHERE u.ID = ?;
```

Also notice the `coalesce()`, just in case the `users.extra_concurrents` column is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

When you join the tables you can call the columns from the other table

```
SELECT `plans`.`concurrents`,`users`.`extra_concurrents`
FROM `plans` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`membership` = `plans`.`ID` 
WHERE `users`.`ID` = ?`
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use multiple joins instead of an "and". Without seeing your data structure it's hard to say exactly what you'll need, but probably something like this:

```
SELECT `plans`.`concurrents` 
FROM `plans` `A`
LEFT JOIN `users` `B` ON `B`.`membership` = `A`.`ID`
INNER JOIN  `users` `C` ON `C`.`extra_concurrents` = `A`.`ID` 
WHERE `users`.`ID` = ?`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum((`plans`.`concurrents`)+(`users`.`extra_concurrents`))
FROM `plans` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`membership` = `plans`.`ID` 
WHERE `users`.`ID` = ?`
```

> Note : its not good to add where condition on Left table.

Good Luck